# Difficulty in accessing the db records

Tags: cocoa-touch, sqlite

I'm trying to add SQLite support in my app but I had a problem, so I tried to search something on the Internet and I found a tutorial. But the problem is that the db used by the tutorial is read by the app but when I add my personal db (I've modified the code) it is not read. Any suggestions?

This is (part of) the code:

```
static sqlite3 *database = nil;
if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

    const char *sql = "select id,name from myDb";
    sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {

            id = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 0)];
            name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 1)];


            dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:id, @"id", name, @"nome", nil];

            [dictionary release];
        }
    }


else{
    sqlite3_close(database);

}
```

Comment: Your question and code was (and is) super badly-formatted. Please make an effort proofreading it before posting.

Comment: Please specify the exact issue, we don't know which tutorial you used and what happening in your code. Is it entering to the if statements ?

Answer (score 0):

Before the else statement you need to release the resources:

```
    // "Finalize" the statement - releases the resources associated with the statement.
    sqlite3_finalize(selectstmt);
```

And what is the purpose of the `release` statement?